# print a dictionary of dictionaries to a csv?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'201304': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2}), '201305': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2}), '201306': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2}), '201301': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2}), '201302': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2}), '201303': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2}), '201212': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})})
```

I want a cvs that looks like this:

```
month,District - 1,District -2, District -3...... for however many districts there are 
201304,20,9,5,6,.....
```

what I have right now is:

```
with open('output.csv','wb') as output_file:
    w= csv.writer(output_file)
    w.writerows(months.items())
```

months is the name of my dictionary described above. Unfortunately it outputs:

```
201304  defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})
201305  defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})
201306  defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})
201301  defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})
201302  defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})
201303  defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})
201212  defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'District - 1': 20, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2})
```

What I need is 1 row for each month:

```
month,District - 1,District -2, District - 3, .... (as many as show up)
201304,22,34,2,3,4,2,3,14
201305,34,22,1,3,5
201306,23,4,42,4,2,2,24,2,5,6,6,7,1
```

Any suggestions on how to modify my code to do this?

Comment: can you give 2 lines example of the 63 rows that you wish to have. as it is not clear yet how you want it to appear since in the beginning of the question in your example you had 1 date and all districts in one line then you are asking to write 1 date and 1 district per line

Comment: sorry, not 63, but as many lines as there are months. I was confused in my earlier description, should be more consistent now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `csv.DictWriter`, but need to add a month column since it is a two-dimensional dictionary:

```
#!python3
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# populate the defaultdict "months"
# <deleted to keep short>

# Build a set of unique districts
s = set()
for k,v in months.items():
    s.update(v.keys())

# open per requirements of csv.writer
with open('out.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    # wrap in a DictWriter and specify column names
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=['month']+list(sorted(s)))
    w.writeheader()
    for k,v in months.items():
        # copy the dict of districts, add a month key and write the row
        temp = dict(v)
        temp['month'] = k
        w.writerow(temp)
```

Output:

```
month,District - 1,District - 12,District - 14,District - 15,District - 2,District - 3,District - 4,District - 5,District - 6
201301,20,9,2,1,13,1,1,1,5
201302,20,9,2,1,13,1,1,1,5
201303,20,9,2,1,13,1,1,1,5
201304,20,9,2,1,13,1,1,1,5
201305,20,9,2,1,13,1,1,1,5
201306,20,9,2,1,13,1,1,1,5
201212,20,9,2,1,13,1,1,1,5
```

Note: If using Python 2, use the following `open` instead:

```
with open('out.csv','wb') as f:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('output.csv','wb') as output_file:
    w= csv.writer(output_file)
    for month,values in months.iteritems():
       for k,v in values.iteritems():
            w.writerow([month, k ,v ] )
Update
```

for each value of inner dict, it could be sorted based on key value than add to output file

```
with open('output.csv','wb') as output_file:
        w= csv.writer(output_file)
        for month,values in months.iteritems():
            sortedValue = [v[1] for v in sorted(values.items(),key = lambda x: x[0])
            w.writerow([month] + sortedValue )
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in my description earlier. I have tried to be more clear. This for instance will always output 3 columns exactly. What I really need is 1 row for each month, 1 column entry for each district + 1 thats just the month

Comment: The inner loop isn't guaranteed to produce district-value pairs in the same district-order during each iteration of the outer loop, so the resulting table could be entirely wrong.

Comment: @BigBoy1337 add new one

Comment: @FMc agree. I misunderstand po's meaning

Answer (score 2):

You need to process the raw data (a) to figure out all districts that exist, and (b) to reorganize it so that specific values can be looked up by month-district combinations.

```
raw_data = {
    '201304': {'District - 1': 120, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2},
    '201305': {'District - 1': 220, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2},
    '201306': {'District - 1': 320, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2},
    '201301': {'District - 1': 420, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2},
    '201302': {'District - 1': 520, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2},
    '201303': {'District - 1': 620, 'District - 12': 9, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2},
    '201212': {'District - 1': 720, 'District - 6': 5, 'District - 5': 1, 'District - 4': 1, 'District - 3': 1, 'District - 2': 13, 'District - 15': 1, 'District - 14': 2},
}

# Reorganize data for lookup by (month, district) tuples,
# and determine all unique district names.

data = {}
districts = set()

for month, inner in raw_data.items():
    for district, val in inner.items():
        districts.add(district)
        data[month, district] = val

districts = sorted(districts)

# Write data row-by-row. The CSV work should be straightforward
# at this point.

for month in sorted(raw_data):
    row = [month]
    row.extend(data.get((month, d), None) for d in districts)
    print row
```